# How to radio button change form action address

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

**How to make radio button change the form action address**

I got a form which have the following

and a radio button

```
<b>Would you like to to make payment ? <input type="radio" name="choice" value="yes">Yes <input type="radio" name="choice" value="no" checked>No</b>'
```

If user selection is `no` (default checked) the form `action` will still be **register_page4.php**

but if user selected `yes` and press the submit button:

```
<input  id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Next" />
```

I would like the form action to be **payment.php** instead of **register_page4.php**, how do I achieve it.

I make the changes and this is what I type

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

  <form name="form1" method="post" action="register_page4.php">

    Would you like to make an appointment for collection ? 
<input type="radio" name="collection" value="yes">Yes 
<input type="radio" name="collection" value="no" checked>No
   <input  id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Next" />  
    </form>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var form = $('form[name="form1"]'),
        radio = $('input[name="choice"]'),
        choice = '';

    radio.change(function(e) {
        choice = this.value;

        if (choice === 'yes') {
            form.attr('action', 'payment.php');
        } else {
            form.attr('action', 'register_page4.php');
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But the result is still going to register_page4.php even I click on the radio button with yes, I try click on both and both still go to register_page4.php

Comment: What is stopping you from changing the form action from register_page4.php to payment.php ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran As the page got some post value other than choice , is it feasible to do a redirect at register_page4.php to payment.php using header or should I interpret at javascript level and then do the proper redirect to payment.php instead of reroute

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example using a javascript solution. Basically, when changing the radio button, the attribute of the form (here with id `#yourForm`) is altered with the correct action.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var form = $('form[name="form1"]'),
        radio = $('input[name="collection"]'),
        choice = '';

    radio.change(function(e) {
        choice = this.value;

        if (choice === 'yes') {
            form.attr('action', 'payment.php');
        } else {
            form.attr('action', 'register_page4.php');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I make with your changes but it does not work still. The coded is posted above.

Comment: It is a best practice to put all JS code at the end of the body element (just before the closing </body>) element. This will give a faster rendering time on the browser because JS are loaded at the end. I've update my JS code to work with your example HTML code.

Comment: I tried your new code but it does not work still. Still going to register_page4.php despite either selection & updated my question

Comment: Ok, didn't noticed that the name of the radio input element has changed from `choice` to `collection` ... sorry. I've update my answer again

Answer (score 1):

depending on whether you are using POST or GET method, it's either:

```
$nextPage = ($_POST['choice']=='yes') ? 'payment.php' : 'register_page4.php';
```

OR

```
$nextPage = ($_GET['choice']=='yes') ? 'payment.php' : 'register_page4.php';
```

then simply redirect to $nextPage

Comment: But as the page got some post value other than choice , is it feasible to do a redirect at register_page4.php to payment.php using header

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I personally don't like separating out these types of codes, and would make the logic happen in the script. jQuery is your best bet otherwise though.

Comment: Mike has a great answer for the jQuery method of doing things, actually.

Comment: Personally, I would make all the logic happen within one script. instead of redirecting to a page, use similar logic to the code i submitted to decide what you are doing with the post. You are including the jQuery library before trying to use mike's code though etc?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[name=choice]").change(function(){
if ($("input[name=choice]").val() == 'yes'){
   $("#formId").attr("action","payment.php");
}
else
{
   $("#formId").attr("action","register_page4.php");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable Submit button if `checked = No`

Working **[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GKCsH/)**

**HTML**

```
<form action="payment.php" method="POST">   
<input name="choice" type="radio" id="choiceyes" value="yes" />Yes
<input name="choice" type="radio" id="choiceno" value="no" checked="checked" />No
<input  id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Next" /></form>
```

**Script**

```
$(function () {
    var $join = $("input[name=btnSubmit]");
    var processJoin = function (element) {
        if(element.id == "choiceno") {
            $join.attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
        else {
            $join.removeAttr("disabled")
        }
    };

    $(":radio[name=choice]").click(function () {
        processJoin(this);
    }).filter(":checked").each(function () {
        processJoin(this);
    });
});
```

Comment: I need it to be able to act accordingly, there no need to disable the button, I updated my question.

Comment: it disable button only when someone checked `No`, when you checked `Yes` at that time `NEXT` button will appear and you can submit the form on `payment.php`

Comment: @user1777711 its a easy way, no need to refresh page each time. just enable/disable submit button on yes/no

Answer (score 0):

Add Document Ready

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=choice]").change(function(){
        if ($("input[name=choice]").val() == 'yes'){
            $("#form1").attr("action","payment.php");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#form1").attr("action","register_page4.php");
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

If continue the issue try to remove the action:

Remove action from form.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="register_page4.php">
```

Correct

```
<form name="form1" method="post">
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code:

```
<body>
  <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="register_page4.php">
    Would you like to make an appointment for collection ? 
    <input type="radio" name="collection" value="yes" onChange="if(this.checked){document.getElementById('form1').action='payment.php'}">Yes 
    <input type="radio" name="collection" value="no" checked>No
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>
```

Here is a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AGpkf/1/)**

Comment: Why -1 here. please reason it.